# Old kids book about boy who builds a spaceship to travel to mars

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, childrens-novel, mars

I can't remember when I read it - but likely the 70s. The young boy was so enamoured with travelling to the Mars that he built his own ship (which I think was box shaped) and flew there and came back.

That's all I remember. I'd like to get it for my kids now if anyone can remember it.

Comment: Teleported there and back? or built a rocket with three friends?

Comment: Neither. I think I recall it being a solo adventure. Completely about flying in a spaceship he made from a big wooed box IIRC

Comment: Apparently this is marked as a duplicate of the question asked 6 years in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could it be "[Welcome to Mars!](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1407404.Welcome_To_Mars)" by James Blish?

> Dolph had found the secret of anti-gravity and now the solar system was his to explore. In his homemade spaceship he soared through the star-studded blackness of outer space. It was all systems go until the power tubes burned out during the landing on Mars. Dolph was now the first man marooned on a strange planet...

Comment: By Jove! I think you may be right. I'm going to order it and see. I recall him be on Mars for a while and it getting really cold - and the precis seems to indicate a survival story!

Comment: If the protagonist was Dolph Haertel then this was probably the book.

Comment: It was serialized in If magazine with the title The Hour Before Earthrise.   http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?32896

Comment: Available on the internet archive: https://archive.org/details/welcometomars0000jame_t1e0